# I can't make a foor loop to put number before video_title and URL in pytube

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, pytube

i just want to give program a url of a playlist and print the title  and  urls and before titles and urls i want be Ordinal numbers also i new in python

i try for loop and while loop an  i get list error

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist

SAVE_PATH = "E:/"
i =0
p = Playlist("the play list url")

for i in p:
    print(i + p.title)
    print(i +p.video_urls )
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing in "for" loop, you tried to use as index for videos, you can do it using with this way;

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist
from pprint import pp

save_path = '.'
my_list = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/playlist?app=desktop&list=PL4A1F702CEBDEAAA3")
list_details = []

for order, video in enumerate(my_list):
    current_video = YouTube(video)
    list_details.append({
        'order': order+1,
        'title': current_video.title,
        'author': current_video.author
    })
pp(list_details)
```

here is the sample output;

```
[{'order': 1, 'title': 'Stars & Stripes', 'author': 'WSB111'},
 {'order': 2, 'title': 'Lincoln Memorial', 'author': 'WSB111'},
 {'order': 3, 'title': 'Spring has Sprung', 'author': 'WSB111'},
 {'order': 4, 'title': 'Purple Monument Majesty', 'author': 'WSB111'},
 {'order': 5, 'title': 'Freedom', 'author': 'WSB111'},
 {'order': 6, 'title': 'American Montage', 'author': 'WSB111'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in function enumerate():

```py
for i, song in enumerate(p):
    print(i, song.title)
```

you should also use descriptive names like `playlist` and `song` instead of p and i. `i` is most often just used for the Index.

I cant test the code right now but something along these lines this should work. Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Great to hear :D